# Newton's law in terms of pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, density

Why can force be written as f = -dpda where p is pressure and a is acceleration yielding the equation $\rho a= \nabla p$ where $\rho$ is density?

Comment: The notation is a little confusing here. Is that supposed to be $dp\times da$ or $dp/da$? Or is not differentials?

Comment: I think you mean force is pressure times area. Then writing F = ma and dividing both sides by volume gives you ρa = dP/dx.

Comment: Doesn't that yield p/dx , not dp

Comment: No. With pressure $P$, force $F$, area $A$, mass $m$ acceleration $a$ (constant) and volume $V$ we have: $$
P=\frac{dF}{dA}\,,\quad \frac{dP}{dx}=\frac{d}{dA}\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{dm}{dV}a=\rho\,a\,. 
$$